# extra space between command and argument when using minted in beamer class

Tags: beamer, minted

When typesetting LaTeX source code in a `beamer` document, an extra space is produced between the command and the argument. This does not happen when using the `article` class.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \mintinline{latex}{\label{mylabel}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of the extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `[fragile]` frame option, the space disappears:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\mintinline{latex}{\label{mylabel}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]